# Pairing anagrams in a string list

Tags: c#, algorithm, interview-questions, hashcode

The task was to check for pairs of anagrams in a string list.

1. I first sorted all the words. and looped over the letters.
2. The interview continues with a follow-up, to do the same with limited memory.
   I tried to implement a Hash function.

The dictionary return value is only for my convince in order to see all the pairs. I could just print it into the console instead.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
    public class ReverseString
    {
        public ReverseString()
        {                 
            List<string> anagarms = new List<string>();
            anagarms.Add("Gilad");
            anagarms.Add("dilaG");
            anagarms.Add("bat");
            anagarms.Add("but");
            anagarms.Add("utb");
            pairs = PairAnagrams(anagarms);
            pairs = PairAnagramsHash(anagarms);
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> PairAnagrams(List<string> wordsList)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach(var item in wordsList)
            {
                if (dictionary.ContainsValue(item))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach(var item2 in wordsList)
                {
                    if(item.Length != item2.Length || item.Equals(item2))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var sortedWord1 = item.ToArray();
                    Array.Sort(sortedWord1);
                    var sortedWord2 = item2.ToArray();
                    Array.Sort<char>(sortedWord2);
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < sortedWord2.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (sortedWord2[i] != sortedWord1[i])
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(i == sortedWord1.Length)
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(item, item2);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dictionary;
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> PairAnagramsHash(List<string> wordList)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var item in wordList)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in wordList)
                {
                    if (item.Equals(item2) || dictionary.ContainsKey(item2))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (HashFunction(item) == HashFunction(item2))
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(item, item2);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dictionary;
        }

        public int HashFunction(string word)
        {
              int result = 0;
              var charArray = word.ToArray();
              for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
              {
                  result += charArray[i] * 37;
              }
              return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: limited space, like make your code shorter? Use linq http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqAnagramCheck.aspx http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/StringReverse.html  I'd also be hesitant about working for companies that make you start programming before you actually work for them unless they pay for it.

Comment: limited memory that is...not space.

Comment: @Prospector it's not a task it is an interview question.

Comment: if you actually have to write code and not answer actual questions, then it's a task.

Comment: @Prospector it is during the interview, on a whiteboard

Comment: @prospector: I would have serious doubts about any organisation hiring developers without evaluating skills with at least a simple programming exercise.

Comment: Fails for characters outside the BMP or combining characters. There is also lots of fun related to canonicalization.

Comment: @CodesInChaos BMP? canonicalization?

Comment: @Gilad Basic multilingual plane i.e. those unicode code-points that can be encoded as a single UTF-16 code-unit or .net `char`. Then there is the issue that `ä` can either be encoded as a single codepoint or as a `a` followed by a combining `¨`. Both of these encodings are considered equivalent, so you need to either normalize them, or apply a unicode aware comparison function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Algorithm of `PairAnagrams()`**

You are calling

> ```
> var sortedWord1 = item.ToArray();
> Array.Sort(sortedWord1);
> ```

inside the inner loop, but `item` won't change there.

One time you are using `Array.Sort(sortedWord1);` and two lines below `Array.Sort<char>(sortedWord2);` Be consistent in your style.

This

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < sortedWord2.Length; i++)
> {
>     if (sortedWord2[i] != sortedWord1[i])
>     {
>         break;
>     }
> }
> if (i == sortedWord1.Length)
> {
>     dictionary.Add(item, item2);
> }
> ```

can be replaced by

```
if (sortedWord1.SequenceEqual(sortedWord2))
{
    dictionary.Add(item, item2);
}
```

By using `.Where()` on the wordList at the for each you can omit the check for length and equal.

By using the `.OrderBy()` on the chars of the words, there won't be a need to call `.ToArray()` and `Array.Sort()`.

This reduces the code to

```
Dictionary<string, string> PairAnagrams(List<string> words)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> pairedAnagrams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (pairedAnagrams.ContainsValue(word))
        {
            continue;
        }

        var sortedWord1 = word.OrderBy(c => c);
        int wordLength = word.Length;
        foreach (var word2 in words.Where(w => w.Length == wordLength && !word.Equals(w)))
        {
            if (sortedWord1.SequenceEqual(word2.OrderBy(c => c)))
            {
                pairedAnagrams.Add(word, word2);
            }
        }
    }
    return pairedAnagrams;
}
```

**Constructor**

The constructor of an object should be used only for constructing the object. You are misusing it to start the action.

**Naming**

- variable names should be correctly spelled. `anagarms` vs `anagrams`
- parameters should't be pre/post fixed by their types. `List<string> wordsList`-> `List<string> words`

**General**

- no need for `using System.Security.Cryptography`

Answer (score 1):

Challenged by a friend, I did this in C the other day.
My hash-code proceeded as follows for a string S[i] where i ranges 1 to n.

1. Assign each letter of the alphabet to an odd prime P(Letter).(P(A)=3,P(B)=5,P(C)=7...)
2. Set H=0
3. For each letter S[i] in the string S
4. Calculate T=(P(S[i])-1)/2
5. Calculate H=2*H*T+H+T
6. End Loop
7. Return H as Hash-code.

This has the nice property that is invariant for the order of letters (essential for anagrams!) and by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is collision low. 
Notice the hash-code is H such that 2*H+1 is the product P(S[1])*P(S[2])*...*P(S[n]).
Without that transform the hashcode is 100% biased in the lowest bit.
If we use 2 as one of the primes it tends to degrade the hash-code if K such that P(K)=2  occur frequently in the string being hashed.

In terms of performance it can find all the anagram pairs in a 179,000 input table of English words in just over a 1s on a mid-range laptop with a hash-table with only 20K buckets.

That word list was a 179,000 word plain-text English dictionary.

It found no 32-bit collisions. That is where H is 32-bits no two words were found where H(W1)=H(W2).

If it helps I'll dig it out and put it up for review.

Performance is theoretically improved by assigning low primes to the most frequent letters. But given you can't get fewer than zero full-length collisions it hardly seems worth the worry.

Comment: Gödel would have been proud! +1

Comment: @safkan Of course his encoding is order dependent. But I suppose any scheme that puts the FTA with symbol encodings is going to bring him to mind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396005/algorithm-for-grouping-anagram-words